# ListFeed only returns data for the first row?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read data from a Google Spreadsheet using the PHP Google Spreadsheet Client (https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client). After much hairpulling, I've got the auth working; I can add rows to the spreadsheet; using CellFeed I can pull individual cell data properly... but the one that's eluding me is using the ListFeed to pull data from rows.

It DOES appear to be working, however, it's only pulling data from the first row. Exporting the result with print_r shows that it IS pulling all of the rows, however, it's not breaking the data out into the array. I've been through the source for the client and I can't see anything wrong in there, either. Sigh.

I've tried it with different worksheets in the same spreadsheet, as well as with a different spreadsheet, just to make sure that it's not something with the data that's preventing it from working properly.

Here's what I've got:

```
$serviceRequest = new Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();

$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('Prime Pubs Test Datasheet');
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();

$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle('Configuration');

$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

foreach ( $listFeed->getEntries() as $entry ) {
    print_r($entry->getValues());
}
```

Like I said, it will dump out the first row, but nothing else.

Here's a snippit of the worksheet... nothing out of the ordinary: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSK4l.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Yeah. Apparently it doesn't like blank lines in the spreadsheet. It thinks the sheet is done after that, so it doesn't process any further.

Comment: It also appears to not like cells that span more than one column.

Comment: List feed is almost like using SQL. It expects a table of data. CellFeed lets you read and write any cell, also lets you write formulas to cells.